# Creating a New Event Leads to a 'You do not have permission to access this page' Error

Tags: civievent

As admin with all permissions I am trying to create an event but when I press continue, I get the below error. Not sure what to do as I am the administrator and I have all the permissions I need! Many thanks for any help.

> Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. You do not
>   have permission to access this page.

The full error with stack trace:

```
***ERROR*** message:            You do not have permission to access this page. code:                

***LAST ERROR***


***LOGGED IN USER*** contact_id:         2 display_name:       Webserver Administrator email_id:            email:               id:  2

REMOTE_ADDR: 82.47.150.10 HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT
10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36


***SERVER*** PATH:               /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin REDIRECT_STATUS:    200 UNIQUE_ID:          WSxX7MMI3iEAACdaNisAAACl TZ:                 Europe/Sofia OMP_THREAD_LIMIT:   1 HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:  HTTPS:              on SSL_TLS_SNI:        rldb.info HTTP_HOST:          rldb.info HTTP_CONNECTION:    keep-alive HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0 HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS:1 HTTP_USER_AGENT:    Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 HTTP_ACCEPT:        text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8 HTTP_DNT:           1 HTTP_REFERER:       https://rldb.info/civicrm/event/add?reset=1&action=add HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip, deflate, sdch, br HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6 HTTP_COOKIE:        SESSfdfbbafa8321456c2612c2aa8f3eb683=EzRTZMsNft8fTJR8PL_3IhhpfIxiPz_FXSvx6r_gRmY; SSESSfdfbbafa8321456c2612c2aa8f3eb683=L8h63isFkoafI9SSj2MS7IIme2d7c1G5M0bfBDNbWJA; DrupalModuleFilter=activeTab%3Dadministration; Drupal.tableDrag.showWeight=0; has_js=1 SERVER_SIGNATURE:    SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache SERVER_NAME:        rldb.info SERVER_ADDR: 
195.8.222.33 SERVER_PORT:        443 REMOTE_ADDR:        82.47.150.10 DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /home/rldb/www/www REQUEST_SCHEME:     https CONTEXT_PREFIX:      CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/home/rldb/www/www SERVER_ADMIN:       admin@rldb.info SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /home/rldb/www/www/index.php REMOTE_PORT:        65507 REDIRECT_URL:   /civicrm/event/manage/location REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING:action=update&reset=1&id=62 GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1 SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1 REQUEST_METHOD:     GET QUERY_STRING:       action=update&reset=1&id=62 REQUEST_URI:        /civicrm/event/manage/location?action=update&reset=1&id=62 SCRIPT_NAME:        /index.php PHP_SELF:           /index.php REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1496078316.9872 REQUEST_TIME:       1496078316 argv:               Array (
    [0] => action=update&reset=1&id=62 )

argc:               1



***BACKTRACE***
#0 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(251): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("ISKCON London Ltd", (Array:2), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(365): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:2))
#2 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent.php(128): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("You do not have permission to access this page.")
#3 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Event/Form/ManageEvent/Location.php(74): CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent->preProcess()
#4 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(543): CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location->preProcess()
#5 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#6 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location), "display")
#7 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location), "display")
#8 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#9 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(113): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#10 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(284): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Event_Form_ManageEvent_Location", "Event Location", NULL)
#11 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#12 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#13 /home/rldb/www/www/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(448): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#14 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("event", "manage", "location")
#15 /home/rldb/www/www/includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:3))
#16 /home/rldb/www/www/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#17 {main}


***POST***
```

Edit 1:

This comment sounds like my issue: [Permission error trying to create new event or copy existing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/18751/permission-error-trying-to-create-new-event-or-copy-existing#comment20959_18751)

Edit 2:

I did some further investigating and the event is getting created/copied in the civicrm_event table, but isn't showing up in the Events section.

Edit 3:

I changed:

> if (!CRM_Event_BAO_Event::checkPermission($this->_id,
>   CRM_Core_Permission::EDIT)) {

to

> if (CRM_Event_BAO_Event::checkPermission($this->_id,
>   CRM_Core_Permission::EDIT)) {

in Web Files\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Event\Form\ManageEvent.php

and implemented a fix as referenced here: [CiviCRM_API3_Exception: "Authorization failed to join onto StateProvince api in parameter loc_block_id.address_id.state_province_id.name"](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/18598/4692)

And all seems to work! It looks like this is a CiviCRM bug? As I am not sure what else it could be but it seems related: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20581

Edit 4:

Unfortunately my hack only superficially got rid of the errors. The created events do not appear at all in the CiviCRM but there are in the DB. :(

Edit 5:

My CiviCRM version is 4.7.19

Comment: The fix you made is likely to lead to other permissions errors.  You mentioned CRM-20581; I submitted a patch for that, which is available here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10363/files  If that works also, I recommend reverting your fix and applying this one instead!

Comment: I can try that patch and see what happens but I tried and the two steps go together I'm afraid - at least when last I tried it.

Comment: Basically I only get the error as referenced here https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-20581 when I remove that exclamation mark inside the if statement.

Comment: Unfortunately my hack only superficially got rid of the errors. The created events do not appear at all in the CiviCRM but there are in the DB. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't state your version of CiviCRM, but the following fixed very similar symptoms for me with 4.7.19:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/10325

Comment: You are a star! This fixed the issue. Previously I didn't implement the fix properly. Many thanks again!!!!

Comment: Confirmed: This fixed the issue I had with permission errors and 4.7.19. Thank you!